# Show Visual Events in gmail

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, gmail

I am trying to create a chrome extension for gmail where I want the next/old converstions on certain mouse gestures.

this is my content scripts

```
{
   "name": "DemoApp",
   "version": "1.0",
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "description": "Demo.",
   "content_scripts":[
    {
      "matches":["*://mail.google.com/*"],
      "css": ["mystyles.css"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "popup.js"],
      "all_frames":true
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "*://mail.google.com/*"
  ]
}
```

I used visual event http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2 but it doesn't show any event attached to next/old converstion div

plz help me as I am new to chrome extension

Comment: My console says `[blocked] The page at https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?shva=1#inbox ran insecure content from http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/VisualEvent/VisualEvent_Loader.js?rand=1349703403422.` What do you want to accomplish, is there a need for visual event?

Comment: I want to see which event is bind on new/old conversation div according to that on mouse gesture such as press right mouse button to load old msgs

Comment: drag left: newer mail* 
 drag right: older mail*

Comment: Well seems like they disallow that (don't know if there's way to do it). Select your elements and add and handler and prevent the default action. Like `document.getElementById(':p6').addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); doStuff(); });`. But it's a hard work on Google apps; they always obfuscate and change things (that's why a simple click event listener isn't enough). But it's kinda fun to reverse engineer other sites.